# Python control kivy app with web interface

Tags: python, web, frameworks, kivy

I have created a kivy gui for controlling the GPIO Pins of the Raspberry Pi. In the kivy app i import my python file, where i defined my functions for setting the outputs and make calculations. Now i want to control these functions with a web interface, and parallel with my local GUI on a Touchscreen.

I have seen that there exists Frameworks like Flask or Django, my Question is how do i get the connection between my running Framework(like Flask) and the existing functions which are already local used, is there a recommended way?

Answer (score 1):

I am standing in front of similar problem, so here are my ideas:

Theoretically it should be possible to combine flask and kivy in one app in separate threads, but I won't event try to make it because they are quite big frameworks and debugging it would be overwhelming (or making it work with nginx).

**Option 1**

Use two separate applications - kivy and flask. Kivy works as master it does all the logic, controls GPIOs ect. Every time you load (GET) page or POST changes, flask is calling kivy via [grpc](http://www.grpc.io/) to get current state, calculations or to set GPIO.

**Option 2**

Use three applications.
One of them is controlling GPIOs, doing calculations and having all logic. Two other applications are flask and kivy which talk with first one also via grpc.

**Option 3**

Any of previous with database.

In my case I will use second option with database, but mostly because I need persistence of data (past events, configuration) between resets so that I will use some database (mongo) as a medium of communication. Maybe I will also introduce some grpc - main app will have `updateConfig` function so that it won't have to check all the time DB for changes